# How to customize seaborn's heatmap's coordinate and put arbitary data to where I want in heatmap?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have an obstacle that I have a DataSet which looks like following:

[image]

Now I want to customize the heatmap's X axis to "A-Z", so did Y axis, then put the dataset to heatmap, it seems there's no way to satisfied me unless I change the dataset to the form of following:
[image]
Is my thought right? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the dataframe with a dummy dataframe containing all x and y values. After deduplicating and pivoting a full matrix will be created (most values will be `nan`).

Here is an example. A `LogNorm` is used for the coloring, as the range of values in the question seems quite wide.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sns.set_style('white')
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.choice([*'KGORD'], 20),
                   'y': np.random.choice([*'CGLKU'], 20),
                   'extraction': 10000 ** np.random.uniform(0, 1, 20)})
df_dummy = pd.DataFrame({'x': [*'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'],
                         'y': [*'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'],
                         'extraction': np.nan})
keep='first').set_index(['x', 'y']).unstack()
df1 = pd.concat([df, df_dummy]) \
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['x', 'y'], keep='first') \
    .pivot(index='y', columns='x', values='extraction')
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df1, norm=LogNorm(), cmap='rocket_r')
ax.tick_params(labelrotation=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn heatmap with additional rows and columns]

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn creates a heatmap for the whole dataframe, assuming you are using pandas.
I dont really get your question tho. Do you want to change the x and y-axis to alphabetic order? If so I recommend to put the data in order before you generate the heatmap. Im sure pandas has some functions to do this so. If I dont understand your question correctly let me know!

Comment: Thank you, sorry for my vague expression. My question is how can I draw a heatmap that has X axis with "A-Z", and Y axis with "Z-A", then put my dataframe(see my first picture) into this heatmap without changing my dataframe.

Comment: okay, i dont think seaborn ha a function that provides this. You probably have to hard code the order after all the calculations you did with the dataframe and then generate the heatmap.